# How can I change the email address associated with my Stack Exchange OpenID?

Tags: support, openid, login, stackexchange

Any way of doing this, as I no longer use my Gmail account, and can't seem to change the login address to my new one?

How can I change the email address associated with my Stack Exchange OpenID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you associate an email with your Stack Exchange OpenID, you can't change it, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).  Says [Kevin Montrose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose):

> If you've lost access to the e-mail you registered with initially, create a new openid.stackexchange account and either add it to your Stack Overflow account (via your profile page, if you're still logged in) or create a new Stack Overflow account and email us via the Contact link so we can merge the two accounts.

<sub>From: [How do I change the email address associated with my Stack Exchange OpenID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102469/144987)</sub>

Rather, you have to create a new SE OpenID here: https://openid.stackexchange.com - confirm via email - then go to your Super User profile, click `My Logins` on the upper right corner, between `flair` and `apps`.  A popup appears - then click `add more logins`.  From there, click the Stack Exchange OpenID option and type your credentials, click `confirm` and you're good to go.

Comment: `Once you associate an email with your Stack Exchange OpenID, you can't change it, this is status-bydesign.` So the design is to be unnecessarily and highly inconvenient, cumbersome, and time-consuming? ಠ_ఠ

Comment: The link to Kevin expired. Can you maybe update?

Comment: @user1 thanks - updated!